# Trouble with javascript and making it work with my exsisting code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery, and I'm have not used it a lot before so I'm a newbie.

I'm trying to make a slide in menu, and I found code for it. The problem, however, is when I insert it into my existing code in Sublime Text. For some reason the javascript does not work.

```js
$(".myButton").click(function() {
  var effect = 'slide';
  var options = {
    direction: $('.mySelect').val()
  };
  var duration = 500;
  $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

```css
.myButton {
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mySelect {
  padding: .2em 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: none;
}

#myDiv {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: none;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myButton">
  run effect
</div>
<select class="mySelect">
   <option value="left">Left</option>
</select>
<div id="myDiv">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="epi.hmtl"> episoder </a></li>
    <li> - </li>
    <li><a href="kar.html"> karakterer </a></li>
    <li> - </li>
    <li><a href="about.html"> medvirkende </a></li>
    <li> - </li>
    <li><a href="prod.html"> produksjon </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have set, `.mySelect { display: none; }`, because I don't want the user to be able to choose which side it will enter from.

Comment: Have you included jquery.js and jquery-ui.js in your page? Are there any errors in the developer console? You may need to place your code in a document.ready handler, depending on where you've placed the `<script>` block

Comment: I'd also suggest you read jQuery's beginners guide: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Yes I have. I have multiple actually, cant figure out which one to use :/

Comment: Only ever include one of each. Having multiple could be an issue itself

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/rgcya7oq/. I'd strongly suggest you check the console in your version as there must be an underlying error

Comment: Hehe, can you talk to me like I'm an idiot? I am, as I said, pretty new at jQuery and javascript.

Comment: You can view the console in most browsers by pressing F12. Then you can see any errors.

Comment: There are no errors in my console.

Comment: Also, I know that my code works fine in isolaton, the problem is when I add it into sublime text

Comment: Have you put the jQuery code in a document.ready event handler? It would help to see all of your code

Comment: Wow, now it suddenly works! Thanku so much!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your jQuery code runs when the DOM has been loaded. To do that you can place the `<script>` block just before the `</body>` tag. Alternatively you can place it in the `<head>` and wrap your JS code in a document.ready event handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".myButton").click(function() {
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = {
      direction: $('.mySelect').val()
    };
    var duration = 500;
    $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
  });
});
```